# Is there any way to pass a parameter from web.config to HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is there any way to set the `Parameter` property from web.config?

```
public class TestHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public string Parameter
    { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(Parameter);
    }
}
```

If i do the following it just crashes.

```
<handlers>
  <add name="Test" verb="*" path="/Manual/*" 
       type="Test.TestHttpHandler, Test" Parameter="test1234 "/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parameter` is not a valid attribute for the `handlers/add` note. Just adding a property with the same name to your handler class doesn't make it magically work.

You can not pass a parameter directly in the handler definition, but within the code of your handler class you have full access to any other configuration data in web.config; any AppSetting or your own ConfigSections.

Comment: Ok thanks, that was what i was thinking, the general idea was to define 2 handlers of the same type but make then output different, but the general logic would be the same...